# How to add appcompat in gradle?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, androidx

```
Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/24.2.1/appcompat-v7-24.2.1.pom
If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
Required by:
    project :app
```

Here the `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.rts.dcmote.dcmote"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'

}
```

Comment: Seems like there is no this specific version of `appcompat`, do you need this version or any version of `appcompat` will be fine?

Comment: @LiuWenbin_NO. The `appcompat-v7:24.2.1` exists but you have to add the `google()` repo.

Answer (score 17):

UPDATE (June 2020):
For Android Studio >=4.2.0, build.gradle in the root of the project, will be like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
        }
...
```

Answer (score 4):

The dependency:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
```

is very old but it exists.
Check in your top-level `build.gradle` the `repositories` block. You **have to add** the **`google()`** repo.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

In any case consider to:

- use the **last** release of Support Library **`28.0.0`** instead of `24.2.1`
- to **[migrate to androidx](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)** libraries since the support libraries are deprecated. In this case use (you need also in this case the `google()` repo)

```
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are using old version appCompat.

You can migrate all your code using Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX[image]

Answer (score 1):

Note: With the release of Support Library 28.0.0, the android.support-packaged libraries are deprecated and replaced by individually-versioned Jetpack libraries packaged as androidx. The initial 1.0.0 release of the Jetpack libraries provides parity with Support Library 28.0.0 and provides a starting point for migrating to the new androidx packaging.

The existing android.support-packaged libraries will continue to work; however, they will not receive any updates beyond 28.0.0 and will not be compatible with new Jetpack libraries. Historical artifacts (those versioned 27 and earlier, and packaged as android.support) will remain available on Google Maven. All new artifacts will be packaged as androidx and will require migration from android.support to androidx.
You can see the rest of the documentation here [Google Developer](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages)

you could use this one ,
check the last version here [Google Developer](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat)

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that you migrate to the latest support library using Android X, the version you are trying to use is the legacy appcompat that is no longer maintained, try this

`implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'`